# Exchange 2003 inbound routing issue

Tags: smtp, exchange, exchange-2003

Just recently we started experiencing inbound routing issues.  Email adddressed to user@domain.com is intermittantly translated to user@www.domain.com.  This is happening for several users and, as stated, is intermittant.

I don't know where to start looking for the solution.  Is this an Exchange issue?  A DNS issue?

We have a single Exchange server inside our network with an FQDN of server.domain.local with a single SMTP Virtual Server.  The Advanced properties of the Delivery tab of the Virt Server has an empty Masquerade Domain textbox and the value for the FDQN text-box is set to the domain itself, domain.com.

The DNS record for domain.com is a CNAME entry referencing www.domain.com.  Is this somehow related to the problem?

I checked the headers of the inbound messages that generated NDRs as a result of being sent to user@www.domain.com and nowhere in the header is www.domain.com mentioned.

To make my life even more difficult, we use Postini as a third-party SPAM filtering service.  Our MX records point to the Postini servers and Postini delivers the messages to our server.  Perhaps it is Postini that is mucking things up?

*sigh*  I'm having trouble with this one and the intermittent aspect is making it that much more difficult for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that the domain.com CNAME referencing www.domain.com is our culprit.  I changed the CNAME to an A record which references the same IP address as www.domain.com.

I guess I now sit and wait to see if there has been any improvement...

Answer (score 0):

Have you told exchange to accept email for (@)www.domainname.com?

Also, if the volume is low enough, you could setup a mailbox to catch all @www.domainname.com, manually forward as needed and investigate these rogues emails at the same time.